# jquery Validation Engine funcCall not working if only rule

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I have an input field that I am trying to add custom validation to (required depending on another field). If I put required AND funcCall() I can see that two errors are returned. If I only put the funcCall nothing is returned. I know it's getting in the function and the condition because I did a console.log() but for some reason it seems like it needs an initial rule to fail to show the error.

Call:

```
<input type="text" class="validate[funcCall[validatePassportRequired]]" id="form_register_passport_number" value="" name="passport_number" size="50">
```

Function:

```
function validatePassportRequired(field, rules, i, options) {
  if ($('#register_for').val()!='Local') {
    return options.allrules.required.alertText;
  }
}
```

So If I change the Call to:

```
class="validate[required, funcCall[validatePassportRequired]]"
```

I get two * This field is required

Do I have to have another validation rule along with the funcCall?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just add the following line before returning the error message and instead of required in returning message put the function name before .alertText.

```
rules.push('required');
```

@sunzyflower in your case your function would see like this..

```
function validatePassportRequired(field, rules, i, options) {
   if ($('#register_for').val()!='Local') {
   rules.push('required');  
   return options.allrules.validatePassportRequired.alertText;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually started giving me double message with this so I took out the return and left just the rules.push('required') and that worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi @sunzyflower I know this is old thread, it helps me a lot with legacy project, may I know how you handle custom errormsg text?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
funcCallRequired[validatePassportRequired]
```

instead of

```
funcCall[validatePassportRequired]
```

This will add required internally without having a double message.

If you want more information about the (old) issue :

- https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/392
- https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/pull/785